# php imagick convert pdf to png high quality

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I'm trying to convert a PDF to a high quality PNG via Imagick, but the file keeps coming out fuzzy.  Currently, I'm running the following options but can't find the right flags to get a clear PNG out of the conversion.  The original PDF file is 8.5 x 11. Suggestions?  Thanks!

```
$image = new \Imagick(storage_path('app/'.$path));
$image->setResolution( 200, 200 );
$image->scaleImage(1700,2200);
$image->setImageFormat( "png32" );
$image->writeImage(storage_path('app/'.$split[0].'.png'));
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to set the resolution **before** reading the image because the image is rasterised when read, so it doesn't help to set the resolution afterwards - it's too late!

Try along these lines:

```
$imagick = new Imagick();
$imagick->setResolution(288,288);
$imagick->readImage('someFile.pdf');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$imagick_i = new Imagick();
    $imagick_i->setResolution( 595, 842 );
    $imagick_i->readImageblob($blob);
    $imagick_i->setImageFormat( "png32" );
    foreach ($imagick_i as $auxiliaryvalue) {
        echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' .  base64_encode($auxiliaryvalue->getimageblob())  . '" /><br>';

    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When posting answers with code, it is important to mention how your code works/why it solves OP's problem :)